# Delete the cycle animation modifier from several objects

Tags: modifiers, keyframes, dopesheet

How can I delete the cycle animation modifier on several objects at the same time? (as opposed to doing it one at a time)

Comment: I presume you mean the 'animation modifiers'? If so, make sure you make that clear in the question. They're quite different from regular modifiers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following python script which should accomplish your mission (http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/remove-action-modifiers.html):

```
import bpy

def mission1(obj):
    if obj.animation_data is None or obj.animation_data.action is None:
        return

    action = obj.animation_data.action

    for fc in action.fcurves:
        print(fc.data_path)
        for mod in fc.modifiers:
            if mod.type == 'CYCLES':
                fc.modifiers.remove(mod)


for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    mission1(obj)
```

( [Instructions for how to run the script inside blender](https://www.blender.org/manual/extensions/python/text_editor.html#other-usages-for-the-text-window) )

One shortcoming of this script is that the fcurves window does not immediately update to display the alterations, although it does update when you start scrubbing the timeline.